# Open dialog when clicking on event in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, dialog, onclick, fullcalendar, prompt

I would like to open a dialog instead of an prompt. (so i can edit it). i currently have a delete event function when you click on an event a prompt shows and when you click ok the event is deleted. This works fine but i would like to have an dialog instead of an prompt. 
The delete function:

```
eventClick: function(event) {
var decision = confirm("Weet u zeker dat u de afspraak wilt verwijderen?"); 
if (decision){
$.ajax({
url: '<?=base_url();?>testcalendar/fullcalendar/delete_events.php',
data: 'id=' + event.id ,
type: "POST",
});
$('#calendar2').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
var nTime = 1 * 50;
window.setTimeout("location.reload()", nTime);
}},
```

the delete_events.php:

```
    <?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
 try {
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fullcalendar', 'root', 'root');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
  exit('Unable to connect to database.');
 }
$sql = "DELETE from evenement WHERE id=".$id;
$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($id));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to use a html form to edit relative data. this form would be hide, and shown when necessary.

```
<div id="form">
<input id="index1" /><br />
<input id="index2" /><br />
<button id="submit" />
</div>
```

and write some function send these index to a php file, which deal with those data, like saving or changing.

I'm new here, and always searching for answers. This is my first answer, it can't be perfect, but I think I expressed my thought about this question, may it would help you. :-)